# Product collection retrieval N at a time (paginated)

Tags: magento2, collection, product-collection, pagination

I want to retrieve all the products.  But would like to limit it to say 100 at a time to avoid too much memory usage.

I have the collection factory injected in the constructor as

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $pfac
```

Using `$pfac`, created a collection.

```
$collection = $this->pfac->create();
$collection->setPageSize(100);
$pageCount = $collection->getLastPageNumber();
```

Now, I thought I could just iterate one page at a time using setCurPage, but alas, only the first page data is present always.

I tried:

```
for($x = 1; $x <= $pageCount; $x++) {
     $collection->setCurPage($x);
     $pageData = $collection->getData();
}
```

But the `$pageData` is always the same (first page data).

I tried calling `$collection->load()`, thinking that might be needed, but again, not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once a collection is loaded (or iterated, which calls `load`) you cannot change its paging and filters anymore. I mean, you can, but you will still get the same results as first time.

So you need different collections.

```
$pageCount = $this->pfac->create()->setPageSize(100)->getLastPageNumber();
for($x = 1; $x <= $pageCount; $x++) {
    $collection = $this->pfac->create();
    $collection->setCurPage($x);
    $pageData = $collection->getData();
}
```

Comment: in "for loop" objection creating bad, so much every time when "for loop" go through new object creation.

Comment: could be, but it's better if you need to perform other operations on the collection. Otherwise a collection clone is possible.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $pagesize = 100;
 $pageCurrent = 1;
 $pageoffset = ($pageCurrent - 1) * $pagesize;

 $collection = array_slice($collection, $pageoffset, $pageoffset + $pagesize);
```

Comment: this will still load the full collection in memory.